# preg_split not splitting on space

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-split

I'm trying to use `preg_split` to split a string on any number of spaces, after replacing anything other than a letter or number with a space... Here's my code (with some debugging stuff included):

```
$input = strtolower($data_current[0]);
$input = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', ' ', $input);
echo($input."\r\n");
$array = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $input, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
die;
```

Suppose the value of `$data_current[0]` is 'hello world'. The output I'm getting is this...

```
hello world
array
(
    [0] => hello world
)
```

Obviously, I would be expecting an array with two values... 'hello' and 'world.'

What in the world is going on here? The `$data_current` array is read out of a CSV (using `fgetcsv`) if that helps...

Comment: what about using $array =explode(' ',$input) ?

Comment: I want to split on more than one space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` but instead of the fourth parameter, you put it as the third, effectively putting a limit, see the manual on [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split).

You should use:

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $input, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
                                ^^ flags go in the 4th parameter of the function
                            ^^ default value, no limit
```

or:

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $input, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

To split by two or more spaces, change

```
$array = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $input, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

to

```
$array = preg_split('/[\s][\s]+/', $input);
```

Comment: There is no benefit in writing `\s` inside of a character class.

Comment: This seems wrong. The whole point of + is to allow for one or more instances of the previous token - in this case, one or more whitespace characters.